# Opposite of Alternatives in a Rule

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Mathematica provides `Alternatives`, to match one of several patterns.  In a rule, this is used as `p1|p2|p3:>replacement`.  I would like to have the opposite logic: `p1&p2&p3:>replacement` (obviously using another notation) should match if all of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` match, and `replacement` should be allowed to involve variables in all of `p1`, `p2`, `p3`.

If one is simply concerned in whether all patterns match, one can use `Except[Except[p1] | Except[p2] | Except[p3]]`, as described in [Opposite of Alternatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88375/39260) or [Logical AND of multiple patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111986/39260).  I would like to do the same with rules, but the doubel-`Except` construction will not populate named patterns (at least in v10.0 I get an `Except::named` message).

```
Cases[{2/3, 1 + Pi, 3 - Gamma[I], 1 + x}, 
  AndRuleDelayed[Plus[a_, b_], c_?NumericQ, {a, b, c}]]

(* should give
  {{1, Pi, 1 + Pi}, {3, -Gamma[I], 3 - Gamma[I]}}
*)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code defines `AndRuleDelayed` to take a number of patterns followed by a (single) replacement and build a rule.  The rule matches if and only if all patterns match, and the replacement can involve variables from any of the patterns.  If the same variable name appears in two patterns, the combined pattern will only match if all occurrences of that name match the same thing (exactly like Mathematica does normally in patterns like `{a_,a_}`).

```
Clear[AndRuleDelayed];
AndRuleDelayed::usage = 
  "AndRuleDelayed[p1_,p2_,...,rhs_] is p1&p2&...:>rhs.";
Begin["AndRule`"];
SetAttributes[AndRuleDelayed, HoldAll];
SyntaxInformation[AndRuleDelayed] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, __}};
AndRuleDelayed[patts__, rhs_] :=
  (total_ :>
    With[{result = 
       Cases[{Table[total, {Length[{patts}]}]}, {patts} :> rhs]},
     result[[1]] /; result =!= {}]);
End[];
```

(I've put the code in a scope because I suspect that there may be issues with name collisions otherwise.)  Examples:

```
Cases[{2/3, 1 + Pi, 3 - Gamma[I], 1 + x}, 
  AndRuleDelayed[Plus[a_, b_], c_?NumericQ, {a, b, c}]]

(*=> {{1, Pi, 1 + Pi}, {3, -Gamma[I], 3 - Gamma[I]}}*)

Cases[{{5, 2, 3, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 3, 6}}, 
  AndRuleDelayed[{___, 3, a_}, {a_, b_, ___}, l_List, 
   g[a, b, Length[l]]]]

(*=> {g[5, 2, 4], g[6, 3, 3]}*)
```

Comment: This is nice. +1. You could perhaps use `FirstCase` to make it slightly more compact: `AndRuleDelayed[patts__, rhs_] := (total_ :>  With[{result = 
FirstCase[{Table[total, {Length[{patts}]}]}, {patts} :> rhs]}, result /; ! MissingQ@result]);`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks, I didn't know `FirstCase`.  The only drawback is if for some reason the user wants `rhs` to expand to a `Missing[...]` construction, which would be considered as a failed match.

Comment: Indeed, you are right again. I didn't think about it, good point! Your solution is the way to go,  then.

Comment: That is a very interesting piece of code. I spent some time till I figured out what is going on. I have one simple question, when I `Trace` the solution I noticed that the pattern name `total` is changed to `total$`. Could you explain why and how does that happen. Thanks

Comment: @Algohi: In some circumstances which I don't know in detail, Mathematica renames variables by adding a dollar at the end.  Here it seems to be due to an interaction between an assignment and a rule.  The same happens if you do `f[x_]:=(t:>x+t)`.  Then `f[a]` evaluates to `t$_ :> a + t$`.  This renaming is useful so that `f[t]` evaluates as expected to a rule that adds `t`.  However, `f[t$]` will evaluate to a rule that multiplies by 2.  This leads to occasional bugs (name collisions) when several constructions lead *Mathematica* to add `$` to the same variable names.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch yes that is what is happening. I looked at it in the Documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Regarding renaming and name collisions, you may find [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia) interesting. It also contains a number of links to other discussions of the similar issues, as well as discussions which linked that one.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question and I know I have played with the concept before, either for a question here or for my own interest.  (I cannot recall.)

I also like your method but I am immediately struck by the fact that it will not work with held expressions, for example:

```
Hold[1 + 2] /. AndRuleDelayed[a_ + b_, c_?NumericQ, {a, b, c}]
Hold[1 + 2] /. (a_ + b_) :> {a, b, c}
Hold[1 + 2] /. c_?NumericQ :> {a, b, c}
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 2]
>
> Hold[{1, 2, c}]
>
> Hold[{a, b, 1 + 2}]
> ```

I propose this as a *partial* improvement:

```
Attributes[multiRuleD] = {HoldAll};

multiRuleD[patts__, rhs_] := total_ :>
  With[
    {result =
      Cases[
        {Join @@ (Hold[total] & /@ {patts})},
        Hold[patts] :> rhs
      ][[1]] // Quiet},
   result /; Quiet[result =!= {}[[1]]]
  ]
```

Now:

```
Hold[1 + 2] /. multiRuleD[a_ + b_, c_?NumericQ, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, 2, 3}]
> ```

Ideally this should have returned `Hold[{1, 2, 1 + 2}]` but I cannot recall a way to prevent that evaluation in a self-contained way.

**Note:**

- Use of `Hold[total] & /@ {patts}` is hackish but fun.  It will cause problems if explicit `Slot` expressions exist within `total`.  Since my implementation is still not complete I left it in for now.  If I solve the evaluation issue above and will write my code more robustly.